# XmlReader parsing a fragmented file without spaces

Tags: c#, xml, regex, xml-parsing

I'm trying to find a Regex expression to add spaces to an XML (kindof) document that I'm loading. Problem is they stripped out the spaces from the attributes. (don't ask me why, other than size or stupidity) The standard XmlReader in C# wont read them, so I need to insert spaces for the attributes. Any ideas? Here's a same of one of the tags.

```
<LabelLine id="3" Direction="0"X="0.080000"Y="10.140000"Width="12.500000"Height="4.000000"Image=""Content="[1]"FontName="Arial"FontSize="8"FontWeight="400"FontStrikeOut="False"FontItalic="False"FontUnderline="False"Justify="1"BorderLeft="False"BorderTop="False"BorderRight="False"BorderBottom="False"RoundedCorners="False"BorderWidth="1"ProportionalBorder="False"/>
<LabelLine id="4" Direction="0"X="0.690000"Y="15.340000"Width="12.500000"Height="4.000000"Image=""Content="[1]"FontName="Arial"FontSize="8"FontWeight="400"FontStrikeOut="False"FontItalic="False"FontUnderline="False"Justify="1"BorderLeft="False"BorderTop="False"BorderRight="False"BorderBottom="False"RoundedCorners="False"BorderWidth="1"ProportionalBorder="False"/>
```

Comment: Is this a one-off thing you are doing in a text-editor or will you have to do this programmatically in your code on some changing input?

Comment: Programatically reading files from the file system. One time for now, till I convert them all eventually to a different , more standardized format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search `("[^"]*")\s*` and replace it by `$1` and a space.

Comment: @D-S are you using verbatim strings?  Are you quoting the literal " characters?

Comment: Yes I got that, but the quotes kill the statement, even tried to escape them, not working.

Comment: Figured it out... Thank you Both... Casimir and Kimball